# Links to change color when clicked, revert back when reloading page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm trying to create styles where icons are wrapped in  tags. When you click the icon, it will change color so you know it's been clicked. Once you reload the page, the icons will go back to the original unclicked color. This will be used for a page that will have tens/hundreds of icons, in something like a table; so that's why it's important to see what has been clicked.

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dog-icon:before {
  content: "\f6d3";
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 900;
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <div style="margin-top: 40px;">
    <a href="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/dog-puppy-on-garden-royalty-free-image-1586966191.jpg?crop=1.00xw:0.669xh;0,0.190xh&resize=1200:*" target="_blank" class="dog-icon"></a>
    <a href="https://www.cdc.gov/healthypets/images/pets/angry-dog.jpg" target="_blank" class="dog-icon"></a>
    <a href="https://media.npr.org/assets/img/2021/04/27/prancer_wide-db59609b5bd96c9e56e4dfe32d198461197880c2.jpg?s=1400" target="_blank" class="dog-icon"></a>
    <a href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/uw-s3-cdn/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2019/10/08113321/Dog-behavior-Kasper-Luijsterburg.jpg" target="_blank" class="dog-icon"></a>
    <a href="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/EVqxcWQOEnU/maxresdefault.jpg" target="_blank" class="dog-icon"></a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Do you want to keep track even if it is reloaded? If yes. So use localstorage and keep track what is clicked, when page loads, read from the storage and apply the styles.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add a bit of JavaScript code, it can be done quite easily:

```js
document.querySelector(".links").onclick=ev=>{if(ev.target.tagName=="A")
  ev.target.className="done"
}
```

```css
.links a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 900;
  margin: 20px;
}
.links a.done { color:green }
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <div class="links" style="margin-top: 40px;">
    <a href="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/dog-puppy-on-garden-royalty-free-image-1586966191.jpg?crop=1.00xw:0.669xh;0,0.190xh&resize=1200:*" target="_blank">&#xf6d3;</a>
    <a href="https://www.cdc.gov/healthypets/images/pets/angry-dog.jpg" target="_blank">&#xf6d3;</a>
    <a href="https://media.npr.org/assets/img/2021/04/27/prancer_wide-db59609b5bd96c9e56e4dfe32d198461197880c2.jpg?s=1400" target="_blank">&#xf6d3;</a>
    <a href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/uw-s3-cdn/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2019/10/08113321/Dog-behavior-Kasper-Luijsterburg.jpg" target="_blank">&#xf6d3;</a>
    <a href="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/EVqxcWQOEnU/maxresdefault.jpg" target="_blank">&#xf6d3;</a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to know what was clicked and do not want to keep track across page reloads, add one event handler to the window, look for the anchor that was clicked, and add a class.

```js
window.addEventListener("click", function (evt) {
  const link = evt.target.closest("a");
  if (link) link.classList.add("clicked");
});
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}

.dog-icon:before {
  content: "\f6d3";
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 900;
  padding: 40px;
}

a.clicked {
  color: green;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <div style="margin-top: 40px;">
    <a href="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/dog-puppy-on-garden-royalty-free-image-1586966191.jpg?crop=1.00xw:0.669xh;0,0.190xh&resize=1200:*" target="_blank" class="dog-icon"></a>
    <a href="https://www.cdc.gov/healthypets/images/pets/angry-dog.jpg" target="_blank" class="dog-icon"></a>
    <a href="https://media.npr.org/assets/img/2021/04/27/prancer_wide-db59609b5bd96c9e56e4dfe32d198461197880c2.jpg?s=1400" target="_blank" class="dog-icon"></a>
    <a href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/uw-s3-cdn/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2019/10/08113321/Dog-behavior-Kasper-Luijsterburg.jpg" target="_blank" class="dog-icon"></a>
    <a href="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/EVqxcWQOEnU/maxresdefault.jpg" target="_blank" class="dog-icon"></a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you make the automatic (browser implementing) color of a visited a element the same as the non-visited element then on a reload all the dogs will be the same color.

If in addition you listen for a click on a dog and at that point change its color to whatever you want the visited color to be then for that session (ie before any reload) the dog will look as though it's been visited.

```js
const as = document.querySelectorAll('a');
as.forEach(a => {
  a.addEventListener('click', function () {
    this.style.color = 'magenta';
  });
});
```

```css
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a, a:visited {
  color: blue;
}
.dog-icon:before {
  content: "\f6d3";
  font-family: 'Font Awesome 5 Free';
  font-size: 40px;
  font-weight: 900;
  padding: 40px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.7.2/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

  <div style="margin-top: 40px;">
    <a href="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/dog-puppy-on-garden-royalty-free-image-1586966191.jpg?crop=1.00xw:0.669xh;0,0.190xh&resize=1200:*" target="_blank" class="dog-icon"></a>
    <a href="https://www.cdc.gov/healthypets/images/pets/angry-dog.jpg" target="_blank" class="dog-icon"></a>
    <a href="https://media.npr.org/assets/img/2021/04/27/prancer_wide-db59609b5bd96c9e56e4dfe32d198461197880c2.jpg?s=1400" target="_blank" class="dog-icon"></a>
    <a href="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/uw-s3-cdn/wp-content/uploads/sites/6/2019/10/08113321/Dog-behavior-Kasper-Luijsterburg.jpg" target="_blank" class="dog-icon"></a>
    <a href="https://i.ytimg.com/vi/EVqxcWQOEnU/maxresdefault.jpg" target="_blank" class="dog-icon"></a>
  </div>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can try using the :active selector for your a tags.

for example:

```
a:active{
(enter css here)
}
```

i'm new to css so it might not work, but it's worth a try.

Comment: I've already tried that. It still has the same issue of never changing back to the original color unless you delete your browser history.

Comment: Oh, yeah I forgot that was a thing. Maybe try :focus?